# Add a drop shadow to a top-fixed nav bar using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to add a drop shadow to my nav bar I have through Bootstrap, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Maybe somebody can point me in the correct direction.  All the other questions I've seen that have been asked about a similar topic have incredibly lengthy responses of messy code, but there has to be a simple way to do it, isn't that the whole point of Bootstrap after all.

Here's my HTML relating to my nav:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="custom-nav">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="index.html">eService</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  Services
                  <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Stage Design & Build</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Event Planning & Management</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Video Production</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Audio Production</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Lighting Production</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li><!-- dropdown -->
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  Events
                  <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Corporate Events</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Civic Events</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Charity Events</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Grand Openings</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Concerts</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li><!-- dropdown -->
        </ul><!-- /.nav -->
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
  </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
</div><!-- /.navbar -->
```

And here's my CSS relating to the navbar:

```
#custom-nav {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px #FC0;
    -moz-box-shadow:    20px 20px 20px #FC0;
    box-shadow:         20px 20px 20px #FC0;
    z-index:999;
}
```

I'm aware that with the current px dimensions I have set for my shadow it will appear like a solid block.  I plan on adjusting once I can get this dang thing to work.  Thanks for any help or pointers.

Mucho love.

Comment: It is working.  I'm not really sure what exactly you need?

Comment: @F0rgiven You're right, I just tested it in JSFiddle and this particular code is working, but when I test it in my browser with all the Bootstrap code it doesn't work.  There must be a style I need to override, but I can't figure out what style it is.

Comment: What browser are you using? And please show us your entire HTML code if possible so we can see if anything else is wrong.

Comment: Hey Brian did you work this out? I still couldn't figure this issue, Can you please share what changes you've made?

Comment: please paste fiddle, mine used shadow and it worked great

Comment: inspect elements either with chrome or ff, see if there is a shadow overriding yours, if that's the case add, box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px #FC0 !important; to your code

Comment: Check out: https://github.com/shammelburg/ng-scroll-shadow

Answer (score 75):

In your css add the following to your .navbar class rule

```
.navbar {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #999;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #999;

    /* the rest of your styling */
}
```

### EDIT

There is an awesome online tool to generate box shadow code (thanks to the folks at [cssmatic.com](http://www.cssmatic.com)). You can adjust the way your shadow looks and it will generate all the code needed plus any specific browser prefixes (webkit, mozilla, etc.). You then can copy the code into your css.

http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow

You can also find other css effects in the same site.

Answer (score 5):

To maintain shadow in your navbar simply adjust box-shadow properties

```
.navbar{
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 8px -6px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    }
```

Here the first `0px` is to make the shadow in center adjust it to get right and left-sided shadow

then, `8px` is for height of the shadow

after that `8px` and `-6px` is for hardness and opacity of the shadow

`(0,0,0,0.5)` is simple rgba(red,green,blue,alpha) colors and **alpha,** it is to maintain **transparency** of the shadow it goes **0.0**(fully transparent) to **1.0**(fully opaque)

Answer (score 2):

Your `navbar` markup is a bit different from the default Bootstrap `navbar` markup, for example,

You wrapped your whole `navbar` in a class named `navbar-inner` instead of wrapping the `toggle` and `brand` inside a `navbar-header` class followed by the collapsible `menu-items` after.

Here's how your mark-up should look like:

```css
#custom-nav {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px #FC0;
  -moz-box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px #FC0;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px #FC0;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="custom-nav" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">eService</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      Services
                      <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Stage Design & Build</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Event Planning & Management</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Video Production</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Audio Production</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lighting Production</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- dropdown -->
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                      Events
                      <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Corporate Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Civic Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Charity Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grand Openings</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Concerts</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- dropdown -->
    </ul>
    <!-- /.nav -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, keep your custom `css` file **below** your bootstrap `css` file to avoid your styles being overwritten by bootstrap's default styling.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css"> <!--call your bootstrap first-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"><!-- followed by your custom css after-->
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/36/) with above codes.